# Finding $f(9999)$ if $f(1) = 2$ and $f(mn) = f(m) \, f(n) - f(m+n) + 1001$ for $m$ or $n$ equal to $1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, induction, problem-solving, functional-equations

> Given a function $f$ is defined for integers $m$ and $n$ as given:
>   $$f(mn) = f(m)\,f(n) - f(m+n) + 1001$$
>   where either $m$ or $n$ is equal to $1$, and $f(1) = 2$.
>
> The problem itself is to prove that $$f(x) = f(x-1) + 1001$$ in order to find the value of $f(9999)$.

As such, what I've already tried is:
Replacing $n$ as $1$ and $m$ as $x$, and trying to solve from there.

$$f(x) = f(1) * f(x) - f(x+1) + 1001$$
$$f(x) = 2 * f(x) - f(x+1) + 1001,$$

Although I'm not sure how I should continue from here, it did occur that the negative sign could be manipulated in some way, but I'm fairly certain that $-f(x+1)$, cannot be rewritten as $f(-x-1)$, or anything of the sorts.

So if anyone has any thoughts or insight as how I should proceed, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an oddly specific functional equation: "where either $m$ or $n$ is equal to $1$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got $$f(x)=2f(x)-f(x+1)+1001$$Now, let's find $f(x+1)$ using $f(x)$:$$f(x)=2f(x)-f(x+1)+1001\iff f(x+1)=f(x)+1001$$Now, let $y=x+1, x=y-1$ you get $$f(y)=f(y-1)+1001$$

(Note, both $x$ and $y$ are just names of the variables, so if it is more convenient to you, you can rewrite the final line using $x$ instead of $y$)

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer.**    This is an attempt to see what happens if I drop the conditions that $f(1)=2$ and that at least one of $m$ and $n$ in the functional equation must be $1$.  That is, this answer does not answer the OP's question, but I think it is a nice relevant question.  Since the work is quite long, I have to put it here as an answer.

---

Fix $k\in\mathbb{C}$.  Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function satisfying
$$f(mn)=f(m)\,f(n)-f(m+n)+k$$
for all $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.  Write $a:=f(1)$.  Then, plugging in $m=1$, we have
$$f(n+1)=(a-1)\,f(n)+k\tag{*}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.  We have three notable scenarios: $a=1$, $a=2$, and $a\notin\{1,2\}$.

---

If $a=1$, then $f(n)=k$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$.  That means
$$k=f(4)=f(2\cdot2)=f(2)\,f(2)-f(2+2)+k=k\cdot k-k+k\,.$$
Thus, $k^2=k$, or $k\in\{0,1\}$.   Hence, there are two possible solutions with $f(1)=1$:

- $k=0$, which gives $f(1)=1$ and $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$;
- $k=1$, which gives $f(n)=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

---

Now, we suppose that $a=2$.  Thus, $f(n+1)=f(n)+k$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.  This leads to $f(n)=2+k(n-1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.   Consequently,
$$3k+2=f(4)=f(2\cdot 2)=f(2)\,f(2)-f(2+2)+k=(k+2)^2-(3k+2)+k\,,$$
yielding
$$k^2-k=0\,.$$
Thus, $k=0$ or $k=1$.  If $k=0$, then $f(n)=2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.  If $k=1$, then $f(n)=n+1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

---

Finally, we tackle the case $a\notin \{1,2\}$.  Then, the solution to the recurrence relation (*) is
$$f(n)=(a-1)^{n-1}\left(a+\frac{k}{a-2}\right)-\frac{k}{a-2}\,.$$
In particular, $f(2)=a(a-1)+k$ and $f(4)=a(a-1)^3+\left((a-1)^2+(a-1)+1\right)k$.  Using the same equation $2\,f(4)=\big(f(2)\big)^2+k$ from before, we get
$$2a(a-1)^3+2\left((a-1)^2+(a-1)+1\right)k=\big(a(a-1)+k\big)^2+k\,.$$
Thus,
$$a(a-2)(a-1)^2=k(k-1)\,.$$
This means $k=(a-1)^2$ or $k=-a(a-2)$.  For the subcase $k=-a(a-2)$, we see that
$$f(n)=a\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\,.$$

---

For the subcase $k=(a-1)^2$, we get
$$f(n)=a(a-1)^{n-1}+(a-1)^2\left(\frac{(a-1)^{n-1}-1}{a-2}\right)\text{ for each integer }n>0\,.$$
For simplicity, write $b:=a-1$, so $k=b^2$ and $f(n)=(b+1)b^{n-1}+b^2\left(\dfrac{b^{n-1}-1}{b-1}\right)$.  We have
$$f(2)=(b+1)b+b^2\,,\,\,f(3)=2(b+1)b^2\,,$$ $$f(5)=(b+1)b^4+b^2(b^3+b^2+b+1)\,,$$ and $$f(6)=(b+1)b^5+b^2(b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1)\,.$$
Since $f(6)=f(2\cdot3)=f(2)\,f(3)-f(2+3)+k=f(2)\,f(3)-f(5)+b^2$, we obtain
$$2b^6+2b^5+b^4+b^3+b^2=(2b^2+b)(2b^3+2b^2)-(2b^5+2b^4+b^3+b^2)+b^2\,.$$
That is,
$$b^2(b^2-1)(2b^2-1)=2b^6-3b^4+b^2=0\,.$$
Hence, $b=0$, $b=+1$, $b=-1$, $b=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$, or $b=-\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$.

---

Recall that $a\notin\{1,2\}$. If $b=0$, then $a=1$, which is a contradiction.  If $b=+1$, then $a=2$, another contradiction.  If $b=-1$, then $a=0$, $k=1$, and
$$f(n)=\frac{1+(-1)^{n}}{2}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0\,,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\,,\\
1\,,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\,.
\end{array}\right.$$

For $b=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$, we get $a=1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$, $k=\dfrac{1}{2}$, and
$$f(n)=1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\text{ for all positive integers }n\,.$$
For $b=-\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$, we get $a=1-\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$, $k=\dfrac12$ and
$$f(n)=1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\text{ for all positive integers }n\,.$$

---

From the work above, we can now conclude our proposition.  In particular, for $k=1001$, the proposition states that there are two solutions:
$$f(n)=1+10\sqrt{10}\text{i}\text{ for each }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$$
and 
$$f(n)=1-10\sqrt{10}\text{i}\text{ for each }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\,.$$
That is, if you allow $m$ and $n$ in the functional equation to be any positive integer and drop the condition that $f(1)=2$, then the solutions look wildly different.

> **Proposition:** Let $k$ be a complex number.  Then, all solutions $f:\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\to\mathbb{C}$  to the functional equation
>   $$f(mn)=f(m)\,f(n)-f(m+n)+k\text{ for all positive integers }m\text{ and }n$$ 
>   is given by the list below.  
>     (a) If $k=-a(a-2)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$, then $$f(n)=a\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\,.$$  There are two values of $a$ for all $k\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$, namely, $a=1-\sqrt{1-k}$ and $a=1+\sqrt{1-k}$.  For $k=1$, there is only one value of $a$, i.e., $a=1$.
>   (b) In the case $k=0$, there is one more solution apart from two solutions covered in (a), and this extra solution is given by
>   $$f(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1\,,&\text{if }n=1\,,\\0\,,&\text{for }n=2,3,4,\ldots\,.\end{array}\right.$$
>   (c) In the case $k=1$, there are two more solutions apart from the one solution covered in (a).  These solutions are the linear function
>   $$f(n)=n+1\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$$ and the alternating function $$f(n)=1-(n\,\text{mod}\,2)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0\,,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\,,\\
> 1\,,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\,.
> \end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

> Given a function f is defined for integers m and n as given:
>   f(mn)=f(m)f(n)−f(m+n)+1001
>   where either m or n is equal to 1

As multiplication and addition is commutative we can assume, wolog $n = 1$ and that is just a convoluted way of simply saying $f(m) = 2f(m) -f(m+1) +1001$ or $f(m+1)  = f(m) + 1001$.  Which means, by induction, $f(m) = f(1) + 1001(m-1)$.

And as $f(1) = 2$ we have $f(m) = 2 + 1001(m-1)$ for all $m\in \mathbb Z; m \ne  1$.

So $f(9999) = 2 + 1001*9998=10008000$